# How to send dot in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to upload a file using AppleScript in Chrome. The file path contain a dot (.), but this script is not able to send the dot to 'Go to the folder:'.

```
on run argv


tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
    delay 2
    log argv
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    keystroke item 1 of argv

end tell
end run
```

I am running the script with this command:

```
nsadmins-Mac:util nsadmin$ osascript macUploadChrome.scpt "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py"
```

This text appears in the "Go to the folder" field after running this script:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Pythonframework/Versions//lib/python/socketpy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, but what if you try using copy/paste instead:

```
set the clipboard to (item 1 of argv as string)
keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
delay 1
keystroke "v" using {command down}
```

Comment: failed again:
nsadmins-Mac:util nsadmin$ osascript macUploadChrome.scpt "/Users/nsadmin/web-ui-driver/src/nsUI/uti/./././"
macUploadChrome.scpt: execution error: Can’t make item1 of {"/Users/nsadmin/web-ui-driver/src/nsUI/uti/./././"} into type string. (-1700)
nsadmins-Mac:util nsadmin$

Answer (score 0):

Why Chrome? Honestly curious, I never have any problems with Safari. Anyways,

```
--set filepath to POSIX path of theimage
--^^set filepath to the desired file path^^
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    activate application "Safari"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down} --open goto
    set the clipboard to filepath
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
    delay 0.7
    keystroke return -- enter goto text
    delay 0.4
    keystroke return --press enter on file

end tell
```

Maybe that filepath is just too long. I doubt it though. Try using this, if it doesn't work with Chrome try it with Safari just to see if that's the problem. This is meant to be run when the "file choosing window" is already open, but the full script that I wrote is a bit more extensive, let me know if you want to see it.